# For the life of me, I can't compare the first character of this array

Tags: c++, char, compare, strncmp

All I want to do is pass in a `char* buffer` and compare that to a literal string `"@"` -- why is this so difficult for me.

```
    char* buffer = "@3702";
    string b(buffer);
    string c("@");

    if (strncmp(b.c_str(), c.c_str(), 1) == 0)
    {
        perror("Buffer malformated!");
        return false;
    }
```

What do I not understand about this?

***Edit:*** haaaa, `!=` not `==`   whoops :)

Comment: Wouldn't `buffer[0] == '@'` be just as suitable?

If not, prefer C++ string operations:

`b.find_first_of ("@") != string::npos`

Comment: How pedantic do you want this? `if (buffer && *buffer == '@')`

Comment: strncmp returns 0 when the strings are equal.  therefore the if condition should be: `if (strncmp(b.c_str(), c.c_str(), 1) != 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare `char*`and use `strncmp()`, you don't need to use stl string for this.

```
int main()
{
    char* buffer = "@3702";
    char* c = "@";

    if (strncmp(buffer, c, strlen(c)) == 0)
    {
        //same string
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //not same string
        return false;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

And, remember `char[]` can convert to `char*`, so in this case, above code is similar to below code.

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "@3702";
    char c[] = "@";

    if(buffer[0] == c[0])
    {
        //same string
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //not same string
        return false;
    }

    getchar();
}
```